# No matching distribution found for utilities

Tags: python, utilities

while trying to install the python package utilities:

```
pip3 install utilities
```

I faced this error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement utilities (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for utilities
```

Is it a python version issue (mine is 3.5)?? If it's the case, which package has replaced it?

Comment: Do you have a link to the module you're trying to acquire (maybe a github page)?  It may be that it hasn't been updated for python 3, or has a different name, or the package in pip has a slightly different name

Comment: Looks like it is available for 2.7. So either you can create a virtual environment with that version to make it work. Or else given that this package is about image processing, use a more current pack like OpenCV or scikit-image. Were you looking for any other kind of utilities?

Comment: In fact i'm following the "Artificial intelligence with python" book. Actually, I'm in the logistic regression classifier part and I have to import visual_classifier from utilities. So when I tried to do the job, unfortunately it didn't work.  (I'm working with PyCharm)

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it is asking how to get an unknown module (unknown even to the poster!)

Comment: @RadhouaneTouj, did you solved the error. If so please share

Comment: I remember this issue, in fact I read incorrectly the document that time. In short terms, it has nothing to do with python or pip3 etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no module named utilities in Python,I believe you have encountered importing a file called `utilities.py` by the line `import utilities`. Showing the full source code might help. Additionally, check the gitgub repo of your source code for a file called `utilities.py` and copy it to your execution folder. If you are talking about `python-utils`, check this [link](https://pypi.org/project/python-utils/).
Python Utilities contains many standard utility modules to solve common problems. They are :

**File System** -- os, os.path, shutil

**Running External Processes** -- commands

**Exceptions**

**HTTP** -- urllib and urlparse

Check This [link](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/utilities)

If this doesn't solve your issue, try installing the [utilities-package](https://pypi.org/project/utilities-package/) using :

```
pip install utilities-package
```